# Is it possible to force scroll of selectManyCheckbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, primefaces

I have pretty long [selectManyCheckbox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml) inside `scrollPanel`. User selection is saved and when page is loaded top `selectManyCheckbox` elements are shown.

Is it possible to force `selectManyCheckbox` scroll to the first selected element to show user that some elements are already checked. How to do this?

Source code:

```
<p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="height: 200px;">
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="templates" value="#{myBean.selectedTemplates}" layout="pageDirection">
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myTemplates}" var="template" 
                                   itemValue="#{template.id}" itemLabel="#{template.name}"/>
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

Comment: `selectManyCheckbox` is a custom component, we need the source code to debug that.

Comment: It is PrimeFaces component p:selectManyCheckbox. Sorry for being not precise